# D3 x-axis date labels are showing as decimals

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As the title says, my labels show up as decimals when I'm expecting something like `June 6 2020`.

I tried inputting `xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format("d"))` and, while it does show up as months, they are the wrong months. I've also tried instantiating my data dates as `new Date(2020-04-06)` instead of just `2020-04-06` but still to no avail. Is there something I'm missing?

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lorenzoang/tm0j1zvp/)

[image: Chart with wrong x-labels]

EDIT: Finally [found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43774263/3939909) after a bit more Googling. In case anyone runs into the same issue, you first need to pass the date as a string and then format it with D3 like so:

```
var dataRaw = [
         {'date': '2020-06-01', 'value': 0'},
    ]
dataRaw.forEach(function(d){
    d.date = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date)
})
var data = Object.assign(dataRaw.map(({date, value}) => ({date, value})), {y: "₱ Portfolio Value"})
```